# Solving differential equations, without 'time' in the equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

If two equations are presented, both being rates of change (with respect to time), how would one solve one specifically, when only the following information is provided?

$$\frac{dl}{dt}=-2l$$
$$\frac{dm}{dt}=2l-3m$$
And that at $t=0, l=2,\!000$ and $m=1,\!000$.

The goal is to be able to find $m$ (and $l$, if possible) with only the information provided above. I have attempting 'flipping' the equations to receive $\frac{dt}{dm}$ and $\frac{dt}{dl}$, derived, and integrated values, however all calculations send me in a circle.

What is desired is to find $m$ (and $l$) in terms of $t$, and only $t$. How is this achieved?

Comment: Integrate the first equation to get $l(t)$ and, using it, integrate the second to get $m(t)$. It could be simple (I guess)

Comment: You don't mention any tools you have to solve differential equations. Do you know of 1) integrating factors 2) exponential matrices 3) Laplace transforms 4) ... ? If you are supposed to solve this, you must have a tool to do so.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - can that be done so simply, when $t$ isn't present in $\frac{dl}{dt}$ nor $\frac{dm}{dt}$ on the right-hand sides?

Comment: @mickep - We don't know Laplace Transformations, and matrices aren't intended to be involved in this - integration $factors$ doesn't ring a bell - while I could indeed lack sufficient knowledge for this question (which isn't likely). Currently, only been working off simple integration, derivation and rearranging equations.

Comment: In general, the absence of $t$ makes things much easier.

Comment: These are so-called [autonomous differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)). To solve the specific system in your question, consider $k=m-2\ell$ then $\ell'=-2\ell$ and $k'=-3k$. Can you solve this system for $(\ell,k)$, then recover $(\ell,m)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily solve the first equation. It is the simplest form of differential equation called "DE with separable variables".

See this page for details:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables

The result should be $l(t) = 2000e^{-2t}$ if you solve it correctly.

Once you have $l(t)$, the second equation becomes a "linear differential equation" of the first order which can be solved through a more complicated, but still quite formulaic approach you can find in any calculus textbook, or alternatively, here:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/First-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html

Comment: You say that once I have $l(t)$, the second equation becomes a "linear differential equation", however the Wolfram link appears to operate on the form $F(x, y) = X(x) Y(y)$, while the second equation I have is of the form $X(x) + Y(y)$? Wolfram appears to be dealing with multiplication, while it seems I have addition.

Comment: @user268360 Start reading from "Any first-order ODE of the form" onward...